# Setting the default the value from one grid to another grid in same screen

Tags: acumatica

I tried but the value is getting updated when I selected any filed in the grid then say save.

```
protected void TSFormulaByProds_DefaultSiteID_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (TSFormulaByProds)e.Row;          

    TSFormula tSFormula = PXSelect<TSFormula>.Select(this);

    if (tSFormula.DefaultSiteID != null)
    {
        e.ReturnValue = tSFormula.DefaultSiteID;

    }
}
```

I want to update another grid  value before save and after selecting the first field from the grid

Comment: The FieldSelecting event is fired every time the data record is loaded in the graph which occurs with every modification of that cache type and is not the proper location for this logic.

Comment: Thanks for replay "Joshua Van Hoesen" suggest me with a piece of code that I can try

Answer (score 1):

If you need to initialize a field FieldDefaulting is the appropriate event.

```
protected void TSFormulaByProds_DefaultSiteID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue = yourValueHere;
}
```

It will be executed when a new DAC row is inserted.

If you need to re-trigger the Defaulting logic from another event you can do:

```
object newValue;
Cache[typeof(TSFormulaByProds)].RaiseFieldDefaulting<TSFormulaByProds.DefaultSiteID>(yourTSFormulaByProdsDACRow, out newValue);
```